# Trouble building the ROS wrapper for the Intel RealSense camera

Tags: ros, realsense

I am having trouble building the ROS wrapper for the Intel RealSense camera.

This is the error message I am seeing:

> `IOError: could not find ddynamic_reconfigure among message packages`. Does that package have a  on message_generation in its package.xml?

I am following the instructions [here](https://github.com/intel-ros/realsense). I get the above error when I run this command:

> `catkin_make -DCATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING=False -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release`

I installed the *RealSense SDK2.0* from the [Debian Package](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/blob/master/doc/distribution_linux.md#installing-the-packages). I verified the SDK install by running

> realsense-viewer

I am working on *ROS Kinetic*, on *Ubuntu 16.04*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add `message_generation` as `build_depends` in `package.xml` and in `COMPONENTS` in `CMakeLists.txt`.

Quick Look at their Github Showed [The Answer](https://github.com/intel-ros/realsense/pull/624/files)